# Is it possible to update Nautilus/Files places directories?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Is it possible to add new folders to the places list in Gnome Files?
I'm talking about this list:

[image]

Now I'm aware of the fact that you can add bookmarks, like the `Assets` folder, but I want to add my `Work` folder in the list together with `Downloads`, `Music` and other.

I've read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Files) about editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, but unfortunately you can only edit the items which already exist, I wasn't able to add new items in the list.

Comment: Last resort for me would be to edit the Nautilus source code and build it from source. Is this the official repository? https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus

Comment: removed my answer: I can get it to work up to it adding the dir but it ALWAYS ends as a bookmark. Not in de sidebar panel you want it to. It used to work up to around 12.04 :D  After that we need to use bookmarks. sorry :*

Comment: No problem. I guess in the end the source code has the answers.

Comment: With a little luck this is coming to Nautilus soon. See here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/3012